# Use Angular2 for website and API for mobile application with single Web API project

Tags: design, architecture, project-structure, angular2, asp.net-core

We are working on a project to develop a solution with a large number of modules in which the client wants a website as well as mobile application.

As a team we're working using ASP.NET MVC and Web API. So we can create a MVC website and an API for mobile applications, in Web API. In that case we can create a separate BL and DAL and use common logic into both projects.

But now we have ASP.NET Core, so I'm considering handling it with single controller methods, which avoid controller logic duplication.

So, currently we've chosen Angular2 for the website and Web API as a back-end. But I'm still confused on the issue about handling a single controller from Angular2 and mobile application.

- Is this the best way to go with or any other way to go with?
- What further issues may I face?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not stuck with .net, It think the most efficient way(time/money/quality) is using [ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-2-0-is-out/) (which is angular) and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). They are more focused on mobile side, but I don't see any reason not to use it for web too. One app, works everywhere.